# Query returning no results even though data exists

Tags: python, database, griddb

I'm trying to retrieve data from a GridDB container using the Python API, but it's not returning any results. Here's my code:

```py
import griddb_python as griddb

factory = griddb.StoreFactory.get_instance()
store = factory.get_store(
    host='localhost',
    port=2406,
    cluster_name='mycluster',
    username='admin',
    password='admin'
)

conInfo = griddb.ContainerInfo("mycontainer",
                               [["id", griddb.Type.INTEGER],
                                ["name", griddb.Type.STRING]],
                               griddb.ContainerType.COLLECTION, True)

con = store.get_container(conInfo)
query = con.query("select * where id = ?", griddb.Type.INTEGER)
query.set_int(1, 1)
rs = query.fetch(False)
for row in rs:
    print(row)
```

When I run this code, it doesn't print anything, even though I know there is data in the container with an ID of 1. What could be causing this, and how can I fix it?

I tried to look on the internet for a solution, but it seems nothing is working.